# Multithreading in websphere

Tags: java, multithreading, threadpool, executorservice, pool

I have a Multithreading application, so I implemented `ExecutorService` with a Pool Size of 5 Threads

```
public class SimpleThreadPool {    
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        ExecutorService executor = Executors.newFixedThreadPool(5);
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
          Runnable worker = new WorkerThread("" + i);
          executor.execute(worker);
        }
        executor.shutdown();
        while (!executor.isTerminated()) {
        }
        System.out.println("Finished all threads");
    }
}
```

The application will be deployed in Websphere Web server in with settings contain a Thread Pool configuration :  Application servers >  > Thread Pools > Default, the Maximum Size is set to 60.

My question is, which Pool size configuration is taken, does the configuration in Websphere override the one in the code(5 threads) ?

Comment: Your question does not make sense to me. Can you clarify abit more?

Comment: If you find my answer helpful - can you consider accepting it?

Comment: And unrelated: such "empty" loops : `while (!executor.isTerminated()) { }` are **dangerous**. You are doing "hot" waiting here; this means the CPU will be spinning 100% waiting for the condition to become true - it will make billions of calls to that method within a few seconds. You really want to put some "sleep(xxx)" call into the loop body here!

Comment: It's more like what kind of relation exists between the 60 threads created by Websphere, and the 5 threads used internally in the code.

Comment: @GhostCat I appreciate your replies, I don't see how can I upvote your responses, as I already did it for both o you.

Comment: @GhostCat as for the earlier question, do you have any idea what kind of relation exists between the 60 threads created by Websphere, and the 5 threads used internally in the code

Is it like this: each Websphere Thread treating one demand gonna initiate 5 internal green threads ?

Comment: Maybe I put that comment in the wrong place :-)

Comment: I think: there is no relation. Just different thread objects, managed by different pools.

Comment: @GhostCat There's no relation between both object types, but when server is fully charged, I can see 210  Thread count.

Thought, the APM I use(Dynatrace) mix both types !

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Those two things have nothing to do with each other.

The **server** setting is about threads used by the server. See the [documentation](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/ja/ssw_i5_54/rzamy/50/admin/help/uejb_rthrd.html):

> Use this page to configure a group of threads that an application server uses. Requests are sent to the server through any of the HTTP transports. A thread pool enables components of the server to reuse threads to eliminate the need to create new threads at run time. Creating new threads expends time and resources.

Now, your **application** code creates its own independent thread pool.

Which has **nothing** to do with that system pool.

Of course, it might be possible for your application to send "tasks" to that system thread pool; making use of it that way.

Comment: Thx for your Answer.

Answer (score 2):

No, those will be differrent thread pools.

The one with 60 threads needs to be obatined via jndi service by name. Websphere thread pool is a bit different. For example, it has support of JTA (distributed) transactions. You can use JTA transactions only inside those special thread pools.

The local one will have 5 threads and is not affected by Websphere by any means. You can check number of threads by submitting a lot of tasks and then printing thread stacks via *jstack* or *kill -3* command.